# Getting value from dynamically added date selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get a value from a dynamically added bootstrap date selector. The `contenteditable` table that holds the **datepicker** has the rows below, created in static HTML:

```
<td contenteditable="true" class="t_deposit"></td>
<td contenteditable="false" class="t_start"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="t_start_date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" ></td>
<td contenteditable="false" class="t_length"><select id="length" name="length" class="form-control"></select></td>
```

The following rows are the dynamically created ones

```
 $('#add').click(function(){
     count = count + 1;
     var html_code = "<tr id='row"+count+"'>";
     html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='t_deposit'></td>";
     html_code += "<td contenteditable='false' class='t_start'><input type='text' class='form-control' id='t_start_date' placeholder='DD/MM/YYYY'></td>";
     html_code += "<td contenteditable='false' class='t_length'><select id='length' class='form-control'></select></td>";
     html_code += "</tr>";  
     $('#crud_table').append(html_code);
     start_date();
```

Using jQuery, I can get the value for the deposit field using:

```
$('.t_deposit').each(function(){
    t_deposit.push($(this).text());
});
```

But I can not get the value of the dynamically added date selector using something similar. So far I can only get the values from the first date picker, which is not dynamically added.

EDIT: **Solved** Used nested classnames

```
$('#crud_table input').each(function(){
t_start.push($(this).val());
});
$('#crud_table select').each(function(){
t_duration.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: try using the "on" function for dynamic content.

Comment: I fixed this just now, funny how often you spend a day trying to do something and first thing next morning you get it working on second or third try.